# What facilities do Etihad Airways offer for a long layover in Abu Dhabi?

Tags: transit, abu-dhabi, etihad

I am travelling from Düsseldorf, Germany to Dhaka, Bangladesh by Etihad Airways. My transit is in Abu Dhabi and transit time is seven hours.

Will I get any hotel room or any kind of facility?

I remember I was offered hotel when I travelled by Emirates.

Comment: Did you ask them ?

Comment: I was looking on their website for relevant information. Did not find any. I have bought ticket from travel agency. They could not provide me this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you on Economy and is this layover during the day , then most likely they will not give you anything at all.

Airlines give you hotel rooms only for overnight layovers more than 8 hours

I would feel lucky if they give me some snacks for such a layover.

Story is different if you are flying First or Business and in that case you wouldnt be asking this question at all .

PS. I have flown Etihad only twice.